# Bind int? property to null if value is a non-numeric, non-empty string

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a viewmodel with a property of type int?.

If the send value is an integer or is empty it works fine. When the value is a string an exception is thrown 'Could not convert string to integer'

Would it be possible to change the behavior of the binding that instead of throwing a error it would bind the null value ?

I've created a modelbinder class for typeof(int?), but the ModeBind function doesn't get called. I guess the validation happening before the model binding.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If your public API actually permits non-numeric values for that parameter, you could simply declare your view model property as `string` instead of `int?` (to reflect that fact) and perform the final mapping from `string` to `int?` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have a view model are you referring to the parameter that is being passed to your action method? E.g.

```cs
public Foo Bar(MyViewModel vm)
```

If so then your modelbinder should be of type MyViewModel. You can additionally use a ValueProvider to extract an int from a random string to override the default value provider functionality.